# Changing pickerView font color in Titanium

Tags: titanium, picker

Change PickeView value text color on Android.

I have developed Picker in alloy project in Titanium, I want to change the font color of the PickerView. I have checked by putting the code as . I have selected Real Estate as the background is white, and the font color is white. The text is not visible

```
font: {fontColor: 'Black'}
```

It doesn't work, please check this image[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to create a custom [Android theme](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Android_Themes)

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"> </style>
</resources>
```

declare the above code in /platform/android/res/values/custom_theme.xml